# In Arch Linux how can I find out which package to install that will contain file X?

Tags: package-management, arch-linux, pacman

I'm looking for a package that provides a specific binary, so I can install it. how can I search to find out what packages provide this binary? *(note: I know there's at least one tool that does this, but I have forgotten its name.)*

Comment: Also the binary I'm looking for is `/usr/sbin/ipset` if someone wanted to tip me off on what package provides it even though they don't know the answer to the question.

Comment: Gilles answer is the correct one. Regarding ipset, I was only able to find it in AUR http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=16553

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Since pacman 5.0, there is [built-in functionality for searching the database](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Search_for_a_package_that_contains_a_specific_file) with the `-F` option. First update the database:

```
sudo pacman -Fy
```

Then you can see which package contains `$filename` with

```
pacman -F $filename
```

if you are searching for an exact file name or full path, or

```
pacman -Fx $expr
```

to have `$expr` interpreted as a regular expression.

Since you knew you were looking for an equivalent of `apt-file`, you could have looked it up in the [Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta).

Alternatively, you can use [pkgfile](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pkgfile). Install it with `pacman -S pkgfile`, then run

```
sudo pkgfile -u
```

to update the database. To see what package contains `$filename`, run

```
pkgfile $filename
```

Comment: Thanks for the Rosetta stone! I'll be using that for rpm distros as well as for pacman.

Comment: In pacman v5.2 this is now just `pacman -F $filename`. The `-s` flag has been removed.

Comment: `pacman -F` doesn't always seem to know. I have some files that I know what package they came/come from, but `pacman -F` fails on.

Answer (score 52):

From [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman):

`$ pacman -Qo df`

This will yield the owning package of the program [`df`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Df_%28Unix%29) (at the time of writing, this is `coreutils`).

`-Qo` only operates on installed packages and their programs.

You can to see more arguments in [querying package databases](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Querying_package_databases).

Comment: That only tells you what package owns a file, it won't tell you what you need to install to get it.

Comment: @DavidC.Bishop Is that not the very same thing?

Comment: @Victor No, the package must be installed on the system already in order to query it.

Comment: @DavidC.Bishop Ah I see, you meant "what *installed* package owns a fle". Thanks!

Answer (score 49):

the google way:

```
site:www.archlinux.org/packages/ bin/filename
```

and in case it is in AUR instead of an official package:

```
site:aur.archlinux.org/packages/ bin/filename
```

Comment: Great tip, this seems to yield good results. I created a "search engine" in Chrome with this URL: `https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awww.archlinux.org%2Fpackages%2F+%s`.