# How does `pacman -S <something>` find the package?

Tags: pacman

I want to install `man` in MSYS2 so I tried both `pacman -Ss man` and `pacman -Fs man` (as per [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14858/in-arch-linux-how-can-i-find-out-which-package-to-install-that-will-contain-file)), as well a couple of others like `pacman -Fs /usr/bin/man` but they don't seem to give me an answer:

- `pacman -Ss man` returns a lot of unrelated results.
- `pacman -Fs man` finds `msys/bash-completion 2.8-2` and `msys/xmlto 0.0.28-1` which doesn't seem correct.

Still, when I do this:

```
$ pacman -S man
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (5) gdbm-1.16-1  groff-1.22.3-1  libgdbm-1.16-1  libpipeline-1.5.0-1  man-db-2.8.3-2

Total Download Size:    2.90 MiB
Total Installed Size:  15.72 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

It seems correct – I think that `man` is inside the `man-db-2.8.3-2` package. How does this work? Are there "search" commands that would find `man` before invoking the "sync" command?

(Note: while I'm in MSYS2 on Windows, I think the question is purely about Pacman and therefore valid on this site. I hope...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the `pacman` manpage](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html#_operations), for `-S`:

> Packages that provide other packages are also handled. For example,
>   `pacman -S foo` will first look for a `foo` package. If `foo` is not found,
>   packages that provide the same functionality as `foo` will be searched
>   for. If any package is found, it will be installed. A selection prompt
>   is provided if multiple packages providing `foo` are found.

And from the package information for [`man-db`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/man-db/):

> **Provides**: man

If `pacman -Fs` didn't find the `man` in `man-db`, try syncing the files database first (`pacman -Fy`), or use `pkgfile`.

Comment: Thanks, despite `pacman -Fy`, `pacman -Fs` doesn't find it. Might be something about MSYS2 in the end? Thanks for the response.

Comment: @BorekBernard on an Arch Linux system, `man-db` was the second result (the first being `core/filesystem`, which probably is a higher priority package), so I'd agree that it seems to be an MSYS-side issue.

Comment: I logged it here: https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/issues/1332

Comment: BTW, is there a way to search that "Provides:" field that you mentioned?