# How can I find what package provides lpr in Arch?

Tags: arch-linux

I'm trying to print a bunch of files to PDF files.

An online tutorial suggested I run `lpr *.pdf` in the directory but that yields the error `bash: lpr: command not found`.

When I run `yay -S lpr` I get this message:

```
==> Error: Could not find all required packages:
    lpr (Target)
```

If there's no `lpr` command for Arch, which package(s) do I need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Arch Linux how can I find out which package to install that will contain file X?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14858/in-arch-linux-how-can-i-find-out-which-package-to-install-that-will-contain-file)

Answer (score 1):

On my system, the `lpr` command is installed as part of `cups`:

```
$ pacman -F /usr/bin/lpr
usr/bin/lpr is owned by extra/cups 2.3.1-1
```

This is the main printing package for Linux, so you probably want to install it anyway.